# Best practise for updating single attribute on multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, optimization, activerecord, query-optimization

I am writing an exporter within my current Rails3 project right now. This exporter has to mark every exported record as "exported" (bool). I know how to do this easily in a loop, but honestly, it doesn't feel very good to let Rails query the database, say, 300 times in a row, just to set one field on 300 records.

Does anyone know if there's a good way to optimize this? Should I play manually with prepared statements, or does Rails3 take care of this automagically? Is there another SQL command to do this in one step or something?

Thanks for your help

- Arne

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `update_all` method on Class. From [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all):

```
# Update all books with 'Rails' in their title
Book.update_all "author = 'David'", "title LIKE '%Rails%'"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing me at this. I should have seen this in the API docs. Seems to be exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Careful with this as it updates the database directly and does not hit validations or callbacks, similar to `update_column`.

Answer (score 10):

Since ActiveRecord 4.0 that way is deprecated ([Rails API](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all)), current way of doing the same is:

```
# Update all books with 'Rails' in their title
Book.where('title LIKE ?', '%Rails%').update_all(author: 'David')
```